# How to re-run `mailutils` post-install script after making the wrong choice?

Tags: server, 22.04, dpkg, mailutils

I'm running Ubuntu server 22.04, and installed `mailutils`. At or near the end of my first installation, I got a "window" (ncurses??) that popped up in the terminal, asking what type of install I wanted to do. Being ignorant, I went with the default "Internet", and learned later that the correct choice for my situation was "Satellite".

I can find no way to revert that decision. I have un-installed/removed, purged, re-booted and re-installed `mailutils` multiple times now; I've run `dpkg-reconfigure mailutils` (even tried the `--force` option), but that "window" will not reappear. It's rather frustrating... Does anyone know how to rectify this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reconfigure that one by configuring the `postfix` application.  `mailutils` is a collection of a bunch of mail app packages.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

Comment: So - it was `postfix` - not `mailutils`. Huh - go figger :)    Anyway - That did it & thanks!

Comment: @Seamus The funniest part is, I cannot for the life of me remember how `postfix` tied into the `mailutils` installation.  I just remembered that it is what I use to send my command line notifications to my phone and gmail accounts.

Comment: Not gonna' hold that against you, but FYI `postfix` is [*hidden*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/mailutils) under virtual package `default-mta`.